# When using CommCare Supply, will the WebApps functionality work with supply-point cases

Tags: commcare

When using CommCare Supply, will the WebApps functionality be able to show supply point cases and other CommCare Supply functionality, or are there specific limitations to using WebApps when building an app using CommCare Supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommCare Supply is compatible with WebApps. Some known limitations are listed here: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Web+Apps+-+Known+Issues+and+Limitations